# Communication between Chrome Extension and Theme?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I create a Chrome Extension and I have a theme too. In the extension I made a link to the theme (kind of self advertising). I want to hide this link if the theme is in use.

I know extensions can pass messages if their ID is known. But is there a way to check if given theme is in use, as themes has their own id too? I tried:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(string extensionId, any request, function responseCallback);
```

but it does not work, as there is no way to respond with Theme. Only thing I need is the javascript code for this. No more, no less. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme has unique ID (you can get it from webstore URL), so you can check if it is installed using [`chrome.management.getAll()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/management.html) method.

Comment: Thank you, works! I loop over on the array it gives in callback function and hide element and break loop when it finds it.